# Git: unable to access '/home/OLD_USER/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied

Tags: linux, git, git-config

I've changed the account used on a linux machine from OLD_USER to NEW_USER and now git is giving me this:
`unable to access '/home/OLD_USER/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not to change the owner of the `/.config/git/` folder, but instead to tell git where to seek for global user configs.
All you need to do is change the environment variable **XDG_CONFIG_HOME** relative to your account, and make it point to `/home/NEW_USER/.config/` instead of `/home/OLD_USER/.config/`. 
This can be simply achieved by inserting: 
`export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/home/NEW_USER/.config/` in your ~/.bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

Check out the excludesfile setting in your ~/.gitconfig (/home/NEW_USER/.gitconfig) file.